# Select-ui removes model object from select options in some versions

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of objects that I iterate in the repeat attribute of ui-select.

I bind in the model one of these objects and then it disappears from the select options.

Html-Snippet

```
<div ui-select="" data-ng-disabled="" data-ng-model="selectedPerson">
  <div ui-select-match="" placeholder="Select">
      <div>
        <span>{{$select.selected.name}}</span>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div ui-select-choices="" data-repeat="person in people" data-scrollable="">
      <div>
          <span class="itembalance">{{person.name}}</span>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Js-Controller

```
app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {

  $scope.people = [
    { name: 'Adam',      email: 'adam@email.com',      age: 12, country: 'United States' },
    { name: 'Amalie',    email: 'amalie@email.com',    age: 12, country: 'Argentina' },
    { name: 'Estefanía', email: 'estefania@email.com', age: 21, country: 'Argentina' },
    { name: 'Adrian',    email: 'adrian@email.com',    age: 21, country: 'Ecuador' },
    { name: 'Wladimir',  email: 'wladimir@email.com',  age: 30, country: 'Ecuador' },
    { name: 'Samantha',  email: 'samantha@email.com',  age: 30, country: 'United States' },
    { name: 'Nicole',    email: 'nicole@email.com',    age: 43, country: 'Colombia' },
    { name: 'Natasha',   email: 'natasha@email.com',   age: 54, country: 'Ecuador' },
    { name: 'Michael',   email: 'michael@email.com',   age: 15, country: 'Colombia' },
    { name: 'Nicolás',   email: 'nicolas@email.com',   age: 43, country: 'Colombia' }
  ];

  $scope.selectedPerson = { name: 'Wladimir',  email: 'wladimir@email.com',  age: 30, country: 'Ecuador' };

});
```

[Plnkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/RGuPo2ev2EJu8mNCVtqf?p=preview)

Any idea what is wrong. This started happening after I upgraded to this version. It does not occur with 0.7.* I could not find any changelog that indicated the reason for this.

Target version is 0.17.1

Comment: Wrong target version. The 0.18.0 version has not changed it's header making me believe I was on the 0.17.1 while in truth I was in the 0.18.0. Falling to 0.17.1 solved the problem. Will wait for 0.18.* to solve this since it's doing the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, worked around it and compared the two versions 0.17.1 and 0.18.0

Seems some changes have been done in both. I did not dig too much but setting remover-selected="false" seems to solve the problem. in 0.17.1 this version was set by default to false though now is is set based on uiSelectConfig.

```
<div ui-select="" data-ng-disabled="" data-ng-model="selectedPerson" remove-selected="false">
```

Anyone else stumbles upon this, I would recommend going with 0.17.1 though which is mostly the same.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bug about ui-select. If you set the value after directive is compiled, then there is no problem

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.select.selectedPerson =  $scope.people[1];
}, 2000);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/sGnZcV6ErMPD1R6MG5U0?p=preview

But if you set the default value before it is compiled, then option is removed.

Comment: This is good insight but it does not actually solve the problem. Looks like it is  a bug of ui select, but I'm looking for some way to identify and fix ui-select not change the full codebase with timeout functions that are not applicable every time anyway.